# FileNotFoundError + import module

Tags: python, import, path

I make a project with handling ui in python.
I have a folder structure of the project like that
viewer
  - viewer_controller.py
  - subfolder
      - **init.py**
      - login.py
      - ui
          - login.ui

```
    enter code here
in login.py, there is a code like that
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class LoginForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.radio = ""
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("ui\login.ui")
        self.ui.show()
And

in viewer_controller.py, there is a code like that
import sys
from sub_view import login

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = login.LoginForm()
    #p = main.MainForm()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

    end code here
```

I have no problem if running login.py but I have some trouble if I run viewer_controller.py.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ui\login.ui'

How do I handle it to solve?
please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Keep only `login.ui`

```
self.ui = uic.loadUi("login.ui")
```

OR

```
uic.loadUi("login.ui", self)
```